# Create bins from column with repeated values

Tags: python, numpy, bin

I have to create bins from an array column which presents repeated values: for every bin/first column value I'd have to compute multiplicity (how many time the value appears in the fist array), mean and std deviation of the second column, I want to use numpy but I don't know how to take repeated values only once...
This is my array

```
30 0.78 227.31 270.7
30 0.73 310.79 268.72
30 0.32 141.41 276.87
35 0.45 72.47 212.11
30 0.18 163.22 205.95
8 0.25 109.69 207.49
24 0.3 295.15 197.14
45 0.3 390.97 179.96
8 0.45 153.08 101.1
33 0.36 87.44 114.32
8 0.24 285.9 94.27
30 0.42 326.87 90.97
33 0.4 221.15 96.92
18 0.2 257.49 56.61
51 0.16 194.71 53.96
```

Answer (score 2):

Group the array by the values in the first column and compute the statistics for the second column

```
groups = np.split(arr[:, 1:], np.cumsum(np.unique(arr[:, 0], return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])
group_stats = np.array([(g[0, 0], len(g), np.mean(g[:, 1]), np.std(g[:, 1])) for g in groups])
```

Comment: Works but not as expected: I have 8 rows  but some expected bin is not present(e.g. 35 45 30) and some others are repetead bins(e.g. 30 and 8 are repeated 2 times), this is the output
[30.          3.          0.5         0.17107503]
 [30.          1.          0.18        0.        ]
 [ 8.          1.          0.25        0.        ]
 [24.          4.          0.3525      0.06139015]
 [ 8.          2.          0.33        0.09      ]
 [33.          1.          0.4         0.        ]
 [18.          1.          0.2         0.        ]
 [51.          1.          0.16        0.        ]